# How to define a fixed spacing between characters independent of font-size?

Tags: spacing, equations, symbols

As it can be seen in the following two equations, the spacing between the first two A's depends on the font size and changes if the new AA symbol is used in a fraction.

```
- ${A\hspace{-.7ex}A}{AA}$
- $\frac{A\hspace{-.7ex}A}{AA}$
```

[image]

I have tried `em`, `mm`, and `pt` with no success. How can one define a negative spacing that functions the same way everywhere, independent of the font size?

Or similarly, how can I define a new composit symbol (e.g. AA) that looks the same everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it up to account for the math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dblA{\mathchoice
{A\hspace{-.7ex}A}
{A\hspace{-.7ex}A}
{A\hspace{-.58ex}A}
{A\hspace{-.55ex}A}%
}
\begin{document}
$\dblA AA$

$\scriptstyle\dblA AA$

$\scriptscriptstyle\dblA AA$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use mathematical kerns, that automatically adapt to the style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\AAA}{A\mkern-5mu A}

\begin{document}

\[
\AAA\frac{\AAA}{AA}\textstyle\frac{\AAA}{AA}\scriptstyle\frac{\AAA}{AA}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]